# how to check in pre-commit file to git repository

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I try to add a new pre-commit in myrepo/.git/hooks/pre-commit. How come I don't see this pre-commit new file when I run

git status

Some git configuration or setting I need to turn on?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks and other files in the `.git` directory cannot be version controlled.  You can put the hook script somewhere outside of the `.git` directory to have it version controlled, then either symlink or copy it into the hooks directory to have it actually be used.